# ¿Cómo modificar multiples parametros en un archivo contenido en diferentes servidores usando Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un archivo de texto al que le tengo que modificar 5 parámetros; este archivo está presente en aproximadamente 80 servidores y la lista de servidores la obtengo por medio de una consulta SQL a mi base de datos, en ese lado estoy cubierto.

Sin embargo, no sé cómo hacer la lectura de cada archivo en cada servidor y modificar los parámetros requeridos, salvar el archivo, y luego pasar al siguiente servidor y modificar el siguiente archivo y así sucesivamente.

Por el momento lo que tengo del cursor, es lo siguiente:

---

```
import pyodbc

####   --->>>Connection to SQL Server

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=****Mi servidor****;'
                      'UID=***Usuario****;'
                      'PWD=***password***;'
                      'database=voiceData;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
                      )

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('EXECUTE dbo.GET_localOfficeAvayaFilePaths')


####  --->>>Changes on the 46xxsettings.txt file
for row in cursor:
print('', row[3])
string_map = {'## SET SLMSRVR': 'SET SLMSRVR 192.168.1.1', '## SET SLMSTAT 
1': 'SET SLMSTAT 1',
              '## SET SLMPERF 1': 'SET SLMPERF 1',
              '## SET SLMCAP 1': 'SET SLMCAP 2', 'SET SLMCTRL 1': 'SET SLMCTRL 1'}

for line in cursor.readlines():
    if line.startswith('## SET'):
        for original, new in string_map.items():
            if original in line:
                line = new
                break
    print(line.strip())

cursor.close()
```

---

Cualquier ayuda sera agradecida.

Comment: Gonzalo, bienvenido. Creo que debes separar el problema en partes. La primera parte, supongo que ya la tienes, tienes la lista de los servidores. Voy a asumir que los datos que obtienes de esos 80 servidores incluyen los datos de conexión a cada uno, y que conoces además la ruta en donde se encuentra cada archivo de debes modificar. Suponiendo que tienes lo anterior, le puedes dar un vistazo al módulo **paramiko**, te permite realizar una conexión por protocolo ssh. Intenta avanzar con eso. Luego, cuando tengas algo nuevo, nos cuentas sobre que hay que modificar.

Comment: Gracias Rodrigo, pero el tema es que los servidores son Windows, y mi acceso a ellos es por File Explorer unicamente, por eso el modulo Paramiko no me serviria para esta aplicacion.  Gracias por tu aporte!!!

Answer (score 0):

Si todos los servidores comparten cuenta en active directory no necesitas login por lo que puedes crear una lista de servidores y recorrerla para editar los ficheros uno por uno:

No se que lógica necesitas implementar exactamente, pero sería algo así:

```py
path_fichero_configuracion = r'\\{}\c$\config.txt'  # imaginemos el fichero es en 
"C:\config.txt"

for servidor in lista_servidores:
    with open(path_fichero_configuracion.format(servidor), 'w+') as fichero:
        pass # Aqui iría la logica para editar el fichero y en cuanto termine pasaría al siguiente servidor
```